# Non-hacky way to share a boolean state between classes?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, state

Say I have

```py
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, var, n_calls=None):
        self.var = var
        if n_calls is None:
            self.n_calls = []
        else:
            self.n_calls = n_calls

    def greet(self):
        if self.n_calls:
            raise ValueError('Already greeted, sorry')
        self.n_calls.append(1)
        print('hello')

    def change_var(self, new_var):
        return Cat(new_var, n_calls=self.n_calls)
```

A given cat can only greet once. But also, if any `Cat` derived from a given `Cat` greets, then no other `Cat` derived from that same initial `Cat` can greet.

Here's an example:

```py
cat = Cat(3)
new_cat = cat.change_var(4)
other_cat = cat.change_var(5)

cat2 = Cat(6)

new_cat.greet()  # passes
cat2.greet()  # passes
other_cat.greet()  # raises
```

`new_cat.greet()` passes, because it's the first time that `new_cat` greets. `cat2.greet()` also passes, because it's the first time `cat2` greets.

But `other_cat.greet()` fails, because `other_cat` and `new_cat` were both derived from the same `Cat`, and `new_cat` has already greeted.

The code I've written works for what I'm trying to do, but using a list to share state feels very hacky.

Is there a non-hacky way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like the answer in a non-toy example is likely to be "change your design". This is a very contrived example.

Comment: please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve. Toy examples aren't really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give each `Cat` some sharable context object, say `CatContext`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any

@dataclass
class CatContext:
    has_greeted: bool = False


class Cat:
    def __init__(self, var: Any, context: CatContext | None = None):
        self.var = var

        if context is None:
            context = CatContext()
        self.context = context
       
    def greet(self) -> None:
        if self.context.has_greeted:
            raise ValueError('Already greeted, sorry')
        
        self.context.has_greeted = True
        
        print('hello')

    def change_var(self, new_var: Any) -> Cat:
        return Cat(new_var, context=self.context)
```

Any mutable object will do, but using a type that *explicitly documents* the intent of being a shared state between multiple instances makes the code much more understandable

Comment: isn't that almost exactly what they're doing already?

Comment: @gog: In terms of implementation mechanics, sure, but using a named class is much clearer and cleaner, especially if more shared context needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the same effect, you can link the shared instance in the object returned by `change_var`.  This will avoid carrying an extra object (list) in the method signatures:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var     = var
        self.shared  = None
        self.greeted = False

    def greet(self):
        if (self.shared or self).greeted:
            raise ValueError('Already greeted, sorry')
        (self.shared or self).greeted = True
        print(f'hello {self.var}')

    def change_var(self, new_var):
        changed        = Cat(new_var)
        changed.shared = self.shared or self
        return changed
```

This will give you a general approach for all other shared behaviours/states between instances

You could also make the code a bit more legible by using a property for `greeted` that manages and internal variable `self._greeted` for retrieval and assignment (instead of `(self.shared or self).greeted`)

Comment: How about `self.shared  = self` instead of `None`?

Comment: I believe that would cause issues with object release when they go out of scope because of the self reference (and I didn't want to get into that)